# I would like to create 3d application on android - opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es

I would like to create 3d application on android. I would like to understand the concept of opengles to achieve my qoal. I would like to use camera, light, animations, adding objects to the screen.
Maybe I do not know what I am facing with but I really would like to create a test project.I have tried to google it, but I have no idea sometimes what should I look for. If you can help me, please link post tutorials where I can start. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try [jme3](http://jmonkeyengine.org/) that has [android support](http://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/doku.php/jme3:eclipse_jme3_android_jnindk) for creating 3D with a builtin 3D engine. I hope it's what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I have downloaded it, started to play with it :)